# Автогенерация Access log пути в nginx

Tags: nginx

На сервере лежит несколько файлов для скачивания, которые удовлетворяют regex location:

```
location ~* /(en/ru)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.exe){    access_log /var/www/logs/any.access.log}
```

Файлов не так много (около 10), поэтому хотелось бы для каждого скачивания иметь собственный лог файл. Как можно использовать $1, $2, $3 из location выражения для формирования пути к лог файлу?

Например:для файла /en/disk/disk-setup.exe я хочу лог файл /var/www/logs/disk-setup.exe.access.logи так далее.

Comment: Ответов нет? Подошел бы даже ответ "Нельзя", а то я тут в курилке все сигареты искурил в ожидании!)<img src="http://admin.hashcode.ru/vote/5327/up/" width="1px" height="1px"/>

Answer (score 3):

```
access_log /var/www/logs/$uri
```

Но, учитывайте слэши в пути файла и другие дурацкие символы.

Comment: Идею подхватил, спасибо! можно собрать же в переменную что надо!